$G_\delta$ sets of continuity in topological spaces
It's known that for any topological paces $X$, any metric space $Y$ and any function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ the set of points in which $f$ is continuous is a $G_{\delta}$ set (countable intersection of open sets). A common way to prove this is to use the concept of oscillation of a function. However, the oscillation of a function is only defined on metric spaces. Given $A$ and $B$ both topological spaces is there a way to prove that the set of points where $f:A\rightarrow B$ is continuous is a $G_\delta$ set. If this is impossible, what is the weakest condition we must place on our spaces such that the continuity set is always $G_\delta$

Here's a trivial counterexample. Let $S={0,1}$ have the so-called Sierpiński topology; the open sets are $S$, $\varnothing$, and ${1}$. Let $D$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb R$ which is not a $G_\delta$, and define a function $f:\mathbb R\to S$ so that $f(x)=0\iff x\in D$. Then $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $x\in D$.

@user14111 You could post that as an answer.

@geetha290krm I expect someone who knows more topology than me will post a nicer example, say one where the codomain is a Hausdorff space.

Here is a Hausdorff counterexample inspired by the one @user14111 wrote in comments:
Again, let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual Euclidean topology, $D \subset X$ be a dense subset which is not $G_\delta$ (say, the set of rationals). Let $Y = \mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the topology generated by Euclidean open sets and $D^c$. (If $D$ is the set of rational numbers, this is known as the indiscrete irrational extension topology on $\mathbb{R}$.) $X$ is Hausdorff and $Y$, having a topology that’s strictly finer than a Hausdorff topology, is Hausdorff itself as well. Let $f: X \to Y$ be the formal identity map.
For $x \in D$, a local base at $x$ for the topology on $Y$ is simply all Euclidean open neighborhoods of $x$, so $f$ is continuous at $x$. For $x \in D^c$, $D^c$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $Y$, but it has no interior in $X$ (as $D$ is dense in $X$), so $f$ is not continuous at $x$. That is, $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff $x \in D$, so the set of continuity is not $G_\delta$.

Note that $Y$ is easily seen to be second countable, so $Y$ being second countable Hausdorff is not enough to imply the result.

If we change the definition of $Y$ so that its topology is generated by Euclidean open sets and all subsets of $D^c$, then the same result that $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff $x \in D$ holds. In case $D$ is the set of all rational numbers, $Y$ is known as the discrete irrational extension topology on $\mathbb{R}$, which is known to be completely normal Hausdorff (see here), so completely normal Hausdorff is not enough either.

(Of course, second countable regular Hausdorff spaces are metrizable, by Urysohn’s metrization theorem, so combining the properties of the above two counterexamples is not possible.)

Perhaps if we consider a topology induced by a uniform space with a countable entourage base. This could allow us to compare the sizes of neighborhoods and with the countable restriction we would have a countable intersection. There could be some flaws with this however...

@JacksonSmith A uniform space admitting a countable entourage base is pseudometrizable. If we add in Hausdorff (or even just $T_0$), then it’s already a metric space. Even if we don’t require Hausdorff, the usual proof for when $Y$ is a metric space works just as well when $Y$ is a pseudometric space.

@JacksonSmith (But yes, you can write down a direct proof when $Y$ is a uniform space with a countable entourage base. Basically the same proof as when $Y$ is a metric space works, modulo some small technicalities. The point is just as you don’t get anything more than just $Y$ being a metric space, is all.)
